# error with MACS3 install in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install `MACS3` from source code at https://github.com/macs3-project/MACS/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md. After checking for all requirements I ran the command:

```
python setup.py install --prefix /home/amit/
```

I got

```
MACS3/fermi-lite/ksw.c:31:10: fatal error: lib/x86/sse2.h: No such file or directory
 #include "lib/x86/sse2.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Where am I going wrong?
Kindly guide.

Comment: How exactly did you obtain the source code? using `git clone` or downloading the zip file? If you used `git`, did you also clone submodules (`--recurse-submodules`)?

Comment: @steeldriver I downloaded the code from github

Comment: OK so check the `MACS3/fermi-lite/lib` directory - if it's empty, then you will need to clone the submodule(s) in order to build the `fermi-lite` dependency